# Pod is staying ContainerCreating several seconds

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am launching a k8s pod. I have to wait almost 10s before it appears running. When describing the pod, I see that image pull is fast, but before that, the pod stays ContainerCreating for several seconds:

```
  Normal  Scheduled  12s   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned XXX to XXX
  Normal  Pulling    6s    kubelet            Pulling image "XXX"
  Normal  Pulled     6s    kubelet            Successfully pulled image "XXX"
  Normal  Created    6s    kubelet            Created container XXX
  Normal  Started    5s    kubelet            Started container XXX
```

Is there a way to have more information to understand why pod startup is taking so much time between "Scheduled" and "Pulling" events?

Here is the pod description I'm applying:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - name: nginx-http
      containerPort: 443
```

Comment: can you attach the pod yaml?

Comment: I can't really. I'm not asking what is taking time, just how to debug and find out by myself

Comment: I finally could reproduce the problem with a minimal pod. So it's not related to volumes/secrets

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information that you provided there are many possibilities that can cause. After the image pull is done the component that is responsible for bringing up the pod is kubelet.

So I would suggest to start your debugging there and check the logs with:

```
journalctl -u kubelet
```

Next thing you can do is to check  [system logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/#looking-at-logs):

For **master**:

- `/var/log/kube-apiserver.log`  - API Server, responsible for serving the API
- `/var/log/kube-scheduler.log`  - Scheduler, responsible for making scheduling decisions
- `/var/log/kube-controller-manager.log`  - Controller that manages replication controllers

For **workers**:

- `/var/log/kubelet.log`  - Kubelet, responsible for running containers on the node
- `/var/log/kube-proxy.log`  - Kube Proxy, responsible for service load balancing

Here's very good [guide](https://logz.io/blog/a-practical-guide-to-kubernetes-logging/) about logs in kubernetes which you may find very helpful in debugging your issue.

---

The next common issue that causes the performance issue is lack of resources. I would start checking if your nodes resources are alright and if there isn't any other application that consume them. If you have more than one node, you might want to check how the `containerCreating` is performing on another one.